# Adding new site to Homestead.yaml file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I added a Laravel 4.2 installation in my Code folder with the following mapping in my Homestead.yaml file.

I also added the url to this new project in my host file as well. But every time I try `vagrant provision` the Laravel 5 project (the Laravel folder under "sites") keeps opening up in my browser.

```
folders:
    - map: ~/Code
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public
    - map: laraproject.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Project2/public
```

Any idea what could be causing this? Thanks.

Edit:

No worries, I fixed the problem myself.

Comment: have you tried `vagrant destroy` then `vagrant up`?

Comment: Nevermind. I found where the problem was and it was rather stupid. I set the mapping in the wrong homestead.yaml file. All I had to do after fixing that was run the `vagrant reload --provision` command and it worked!